# JSON schema to force number to be a power of 10

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I'd like to define a JSON schema which requires a number to be a power of 10 (for example, but not limited to `1e5`, `100`, `10`, `1`, `0.1`, `1e-5`). I tried to declare it using

```json
"scaleFactor": {
  "type": "number",
   "multipleOf" : 10
}
```

However, at least according to https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ that does not work for numbers less than `10`. Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

"Power of" is not a function that exists in JSON Schema.

If the implementation you're using supports custom keywords, you can try implementing it yourself, but it won't be supported in other implementations, so your schema wouldn't be shareable.